# why is libGDX image.getHeight() returning zero?

Tags: java, libgdx

So I'm just trying to import an image and set its position. I want to get that image's height and width to offset it correctly, but the getWidth and getHeight methods are returning zero in my debugger.

Any insight as to why this would be happening?

```
public void setSplashImage(String path)
{
    Image splashImage;
    splashImage = new Image(new Texture(new FileHandle(path)));
    this.screenStage.addActor(splashImage);
    this.imagePath = path;

    splashImage.setX((float)screenStage.getWidth()/2);
    splashImage.setY((float)screenStage.getHeight()/2);
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Your code is asking for the `screenStage` width but your question is asking about the `splashImage` width.  I suspect the screenStage width isn't defined yet as the screenStage hasn't had its `setViewport` method called (yet)?

Comment: Ah yeah. screenstage is defined.. the code i actually posted was a revision half-way in to me trying to figure out what the hell was going on.. getHeight doesn't return zero even, so the question is moot.. it was getImageHeight that was returning zero and causing the confusion..

Comment: Could you update your question to make it reflect the problem you ran into?  That will be more helpful for future libGDX users that run into this API problem.  Or you can just close the question if you think its too localized of an issue.

Comment: Done: see the below answer.

Comment: Yeah, but the *question* is still wonky.  The title of the post says ".getHeight()" is problematic, and the example code is using "screenStage.getHeight()".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok solved this.

The interface is a little confusing. getImageHeight returns zero for some reason, but getHeight returns the value you would expect.

My brain wasn't making the distinction.